# Express routes to serve directory of static content

Tags: html, node.js, express, web

I'm very new to NodeJs and Express.
here is my directory structure:

```
.
├── app.js
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── views
│   ├── login.ejs
│   └── partials
│       ├── footer.ejs
│       └── header.ejs
└── www
    ├── anchor.html
    └── index.html
```

I am trying to create an express route using app.get to load the contents of the 'www' directory but dynamically
I used res.sendFile:

```
app.get("/mypath", function(req, res){
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/www/');
});
```

however it only lets me serve a single index.html file, and in the index.html file is an anchor link to the other html file 'anchor.html', but it wont load that file.

Is there an equivalent to sendFile that would let me serve the entire directory of 'www' BUT to the get route?

Comment: so your question is: "how do I serve static content with express?"

Comment: yes but a whole directory of it to specific route path.

Answer (score 1):

Read the documentation: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

The above snippet will statically serve all files under `public/`

Comment: Thanks, I thought of this, but how would I use it in an express route?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you saying: "how do I access one of these static files"?

Comment: So i want to setup multiple express routes, e.g.: /path1 ---->static file in /www directory, then /path2 -----to static files in another directory

Comment: so in other words using within app.get how do i serve up any content in the www directory

Answer (score 1):

You can add a mount path:

```
app.use('/path1', express.static(__dirname + '/www'));            // Serves files as named in the '/path1' url path
app.use('/path2', express.static(__dirname + '/otherdirectory')); // Serves files as named in the '/path2' url path
```

For example, if you want to access index.html in the /www directory, you would go to 
(assuming you're hosting your web app on localhost port 80) localhost/path1/index.html.

Comment: Is it possible to use this in a route path for something like app.get? so I would like the serving the static html files to be a function of my app.get as a response? if possible can you provide the example of it?

Comment: Sure, you could do that, but that would be more tedious. You would have to make a route for each file.

[example](https://pastebin.com/66me5nPc)

Comment: Yeah that was my fear, i will have potentially hundreds of files to serve up.